Old Bitcoin Wallet
I have an issue I have an old Bitcoin wallet from 2010 and I didn't remember where I saved it the only thing I remember is the passcode so is there any possibility of tracking the wallet by a passcode and opening it if yes how I can do this and what to do and if I managed to open it can I send it to wallet like Binance or Okx.
thanks

This question is similar to: I have lost my wallet, what can I do?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
